# Declined very good offer to stay with signed offer, 2 days later my future employer told me that they would not move forward to hire me

Tags: job-offer, applications, termination

I am encountering a very weird and awful situation. I got one job offer let say Company A and signed their contract. But they asked me to start after 2 months later. After one month, I was invited to an interview by company B and got a very generous offer from B. I thought a lot and although I love the job in company B but I still want to keep my commitment and my word, I refused B with that reason. 2 days later, company A called and sent me an email to say they would not longer to move forward with their previous plan. So they released me from contract. I contacted the company B but they were frustrated and they considered me an unreliable and unstable candidate. I don’t know how to show my sincerity to B.
Should I ask A to send an explanation about my case to B?
Thank you

Comment: Why did you interview with company B if you had just signed a contract with company A?

Comment: Is it normal in your industry for a company to hire people months in advance of when they'll be needed?  At least in my experience, that seems odd, but maybe it's an industry-specific thing.

Comment: What did the contract say about their (company A's) responsibilities in case they wish to end the contract early?

Comment: @Steve-O or a country specific thing. This lead time doesn't sound weird at all to me, coming from a country where 4 weeks notice is the norm.

Comment: @Sf02 I applied both of them at the same time. And company B is a perfect fit of my experience and industry. I also want to visit their company to see things there. @ The Photon: the contract took effective at the end of August 2019. And everything from employer is at-will

Comment: Did company B ask about other leads you might be pursuing in the interview? If yes were you honnest about it? Rejecting their offer to honour your commitment to the contract you signed is a sign of loyalty to my opinion. If they don't understand that and take it personnally, it might be better for you to avoid them...

Comment: @LaurentS. yes I told them that I got another offer and I will start at the end of August. B tried to offer me the position and show their sincerity by revising the offer sometimes. B might be frustrating when I refused Them, but I show my passions for the position in all emails I sent them. I refused their offer with a broken heart, I really really want to work for them to be honest. And A put me in a very awkward situation.

Answer (score 11):

This unfortunately falls under the category of:

**Life Experience**

Congratulations, you have experienced an unpleasant situation where there is literally nothing you can do to change the outcome.

Company A obviously will not be hiring you and Company B has made up their mind about you (changing this would be very difficult and probably not worth the effort).

You need to move on and find a *Company C*.

Comment: "It is possible to commit no mistakes and still lose. That is not a weakness. That is life" - Jean-Luc Picard